# UML Event Table: How to determine response of a usecase?

Tags: uml

In many usecases, the response is simply some update in some data in the database and a response to the user simply confirming the action was successful. In this case do I still specify the Response?

In an event where a report is generated from a temporial/state event, and only database is changed. Do I state a response/destination. Suppose the user will make a separate request for the generated database

In general, how do I determine the response?

**UPDATE**

Suppose the use case "Register new user". Should it look something like below?

- Event: User wants to register as a member
- Trigger: Registration form submitted
- Source: User
- Use case: Register new member
- Response: *(do I put something like ...)* New Member Created Message
- Destination: *(then here ...)* User

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing wider context of what you're trying to achieve.  In the most general sense, confirming to the user that their request has been completed successfully is extremely important.  Even if the actual data returned is nothing more than "ok".  However, sometimes it does need to be more - e.g. an order ID for a submitted order.  So generally I'd say yes, do specify - but it really depends on _why_ you're specifying in the first place.  hth.

Comment: @sfinnie, I updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, maybe you can leave destination blank. That mean data is recorded in system (database).

But, If the proses business give a member card, so the response is Member card the destination User/Customer.
CMIIW